# Input live data into AnyLogic

Tags: dynamic, simulation, anylogic, traffic-simulation

I'm currently a Mechanical Engineering student that is looking into a project on Intelligent Manufacturing.

I have been using AnyLogic to explore manufacturing simulation. I have created a basic Jobshop that involves that transportation of material pallets from delivery to storage to processing. My next step is to transition this static scheduling system to a dynamic scheduling system.

I would like to know if there is any way to actively manipulate the simulation whilst it is running? For example, controlling the availability of processing machines in real time or triggering a delivery. So far I have been unable to find any way of manipulating the simulation after it has been run.

Does anybody have experience with real time data input into simulation software?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can always add control elements (buttons, check boxes, sliders, etc). By adding these in the models you can control your model on runtime. For instance... if you have a variable X equal to 3 in your model, if you use a button, you can add the code X=4; and the variable X will change its value.

[image: controls]

My suggestion is for you to explore the different options in the controls palette and refer yourself to the anylogic help to learn how to use each of them.

These controls must be placed in "main" in order to make changes when the simulation is running. If you place them in the simulation experiment window, then you won't be able to use them on runtime.

Your model will look like this:
[image: model with controls]